# What are the basic differences between vinyl, normal (less expensive), and plastic erasers?

Tags: erasers

I was simply searching for erasers for artists online, and I got overwhelmed after finding out that there are so many types of erasers.

So I watched some videos about different types of erasers which artists use. I liked all of them. Each seemed to work differently.

But I noticed the terms *vinyl eraser, plastic eraser, gum erasers* etc.

Now, I'm broadly concerned about following 3 types or categories of products:

1. Some examples of **plastic erasers** I found are Tombow MONO Plastic Eraser and Staedtler Mars Plastic Eraser:

   [image]
   [image]
2. I found the term **vinyl eraser** at some sites. Here's one image I managed to find:

   [image]
3. The third type I'm interested in is **normal** erasers, by which I mean the erasers I have always used in school. They are far cheaper than the others. I never noticed any difference between these cheap erasers (see 2 examples below). Both worked in very much the same way, so I'd guess the material is the same. These are available in a pack of 20 for less than $1 USD.

   But I don't know what material is used, if it's also *vinyl* or *plastic* or *rubber* or *gum eraser* which I had mentioned earlier.

   Two examples:

   [image]

   Another example is an Indian brand called NATARAJ:

   [image]

I'm confused because all more or less look same. Working is a bit different. **So what's the basic difference between these 3 categories of erasers, especially in terms of material used?**

Comment: This is very similar to a question asked previously on the site, [Plastic eraser vs Rubber eraser](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8657/plastic-eraser-vs-rubber-eraser/8660#8660). Vinyl & plastic are interchangeable terms for the same kind of eraser, and all of the examples shown here look like that type, just different brands. Gum erasers are different, and there are also some other types of erasers.  To avoid duplicating previous answers, can you take a look a the earlier question and clarify what you want to know that's different so people can better focus on that?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 yes I had gone through it but mine has additional queries and also enquires about those very low price erasers :)

Comment: These all appear to be vinyl erasers (the term is interchangeable with plastic eraser). There are probably small differences in formulation, so one may be better than another in a side-by-side test. There are also probably users who prefer one over another for their own reasons. There's no good answer for why some brands are much less expensive than others (advertising cost, production quantity, quality differences, profit margin?), or which is the best one to use. There are comparison tests of the major brands online, but you probably wouldn't go too far wrong with any choice.

Comment: @fixer1234 and gum eraser == kneaded eraser?

Comment: Check out this earlier question: [What are the different kinds of erasers used in graphite drawing?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/485/what-are-the-different-kinds-of-erasers-used-in-graphite-drawing).  It covers the differences between the basic types of erasers.

Comment: @fixer1234 that is helpful.

Comment: @Vikas Would you say your questions are answered through the questions that fixer1234 has linked? If so, we can close this question, or you can delete it.

Comment: @Joachim I think so. I'm also thinking if I should edit and make it specific to those cheap ones vs plastic eraser? I'm still not sure about the material used in those much cheaper erasers.